# How to write unit test for this block of code

Tags: c#

```
public static LoginResult CreateLoginSuccessResponse(this PortalIdentity user)
    {
        return new LoginResult(
            true,
            string.Empty,
            user.Roles,
            false
        );
    }

public class PortalIdentity : IdentityUser
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    public string Lastname { get; set; }
}
```

This block of code is for creating a success response whenever a user logs in successfully. I am a QA and trying to learn how to write unit tests. I am not sure how to write unit test for "this" keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` (in the above context at least) just means it is an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

To test it, `new` up a `PortalIdentity`, assign to a variable (`bob`) and call `bob.CreateLoginSuccessResponse()`:

```
var bob = new PortalIdentity(you may need parameters here);
var result = bob.CreateLoginSuccessResponse();
```

If the call to `bob.CreateLoginSuccessResponse()` doesn't compile, then the extension method is likely in a different namespace. As per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-implement-and-call-a-custom-extension-method), you need to:

> In the calling code, add a using directive to specify the namespace
>   that contains the extension method class.

Comment: Thanks a lot...that makes total sense